# Css for fieldset is not working on responsive view

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set width of field set on responsive view 
but i am not able to set width. below link is having Captca. i need to test width for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to align the textboxes properly then it will get adjusted

Try like this  --> https://jsfiddle.net/Prasanth_Jaya/65c6cg7c/

```
<div style="width:100%;display:flex">
     <h4 style="width:35%">First Name</h4>
     <input type="text" style="width:65%" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If You are using Bootstrap, why You are not using columns grid?

Use .row and .col-xx-xx classes.